# How can I change the properties of a cell that is not yet on the screen?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I've an app that consists of a timetable (`UITableView`) and a daybar (`UICollectionView`). The user can change their selected day by one of two methods:

1. Select a day from the DayBar
2. Click the "JumpToTomorrow" Button at the bottom of the table view.

The problem with 2. right now is that when I click it in a scenario where the next day has not yet been scrolled on to the screen, the cell for that day is not selected (see below).
[image]

**DayCollectionViewCell.isSelected** (not being called for some reason)

```
    override var isSelected: Bool {
    didSet {
        self.backgroundColor        = self.getBackgroundColor(selected: isSelected)
        self.layer.borderColor      = self.getBorderColor(selected: isSelected)
        self.number.attributedText  = NSAttributedString(string: number.text!, attributes: self.getTextAttributes(selected: isSelected))
    }
}
```

**DayBarController Functions**

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // To preserve selection between presentations
    self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false
    setEdgeInsets()
    BroadcastManager.listen(to: PrepNotifications.JumpToTomorrowClicked, listenerId: "UpdateSelectedDay", react: updateSelectedDay)
}
    /// change the selected day and notify the app about the change
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    PrepGlobals.Calendar.SELECTED_DAY = indexPath.row
    BroadcastManager.broadcast(PrepNotifications.SelectedDayChanged)
    //scroll to center on selected day in case of clicked on today  
    if (PrepGlobals.Calendar.TODAY_INDEX == indexPath.row){
        self.collectionView?.scrollToItem(
            at: indexPath,
            at: .centeredHorizontally,
            animated: true
        )
    }
}

private func updateSelectedDay(_ userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any]? = nil) {
    PrepGlobals.Calendar.SELECTED_DAY += 1
    let selectedDayIndex = IndexPath(row: PrepGlobals.Calendar.SELECTED_DAY, section: 0)
    self.collectionView!.selectItem(at: selectedDayIndex, animated: true, scrollPosition: .right)
    BroadcastManager.broadcast(PrepNotifications.SelectedDayChanged)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I edited my answer. Actually you have to set up isSelected manually.

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
      cell.isSelected = (indexPath.row == PrepGlobals.Calendar.SELECTED_DAY)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should modify your `collectionView(_:cellForItemAt:)` to check the cell index should be selected or not and update the style there.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be called for the cell I need. In the example pictured within my question `collectionView(_cellForItemAt)` is called for the cells 5 and 7. When we're looking to change the selection from 5 to 6.

Comment: Looks like prefetching causes this to be called prior to it appearing on the screen or being set to `selected`.

Answer (score 1):

Disabling Pre-fetching fixed this.

[image]